# Cannot read property 'categoryId' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I have a problem here, I am doing my project to make a Daily Fashion apps but I got stuck with that error that happen because my route.params

I have 2 files right here:

HomeScreen.js:

```
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {imageSlider} from '../../data/Data';
import {SliderBox} from 'react-native-image-slider-box';
import {categoryList} from '../../data/Data';
const HomeScreen = props => {
  const {navigation} = props;
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <SliderBox
        images={imageSlider}
        autoplay={true}
        circleLoop={true}
        sliderBoxHeight={250}
      />
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Categories</Text>
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={categoryList}
        key={3}
        numColumns={3}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.button}
              onPress={() =>
                navigation.navigate('ShowProduct', {categoryId: item.id})
              }>
              <Image source={{uri: item.icon}} style={styles.icon} />
              <Text style={styles.itemName}>{item.name}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
  },
  titleContainer: {
    marginTop: 16,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'black',
  },
  flatListContainer: {
    padding: 8,
  },
  button: {
    flex: 1,
    margin: 8,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#7CAF58',
    borderRadius: 10,
    height: 130,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  icon: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    resizeMode: 'contain',
  },
  itemName: {
    color: 'black',
  },
});
export default HomeScreen;
```

and also I have ShowProductScreen.js right here:

```
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  Image,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import {Icon} from 'react-native-elements';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import realm from '../../store/realm';
const ShowProductScreen = props => {
  const {route} = props;
  const category = route.params.categoryId;
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const collectData = () => {
    const allData = realm.objects('Product').filtered(`category = ${category}`);
    setData(allData);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const productPage = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      collectData();
    });
    return productPage;
  }, []);
  return (
    <View style={styles.mainContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.flatListContainer}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem={({item}) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemButton}>
              <View style={styles.productContainer}>
                <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: item.imagePath}} />
                <View style={styles.textContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.title}>{item.productName}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>{item.description}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.text}>$ {item.price}</Text>
                </View>
              </View>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Icon name="shoppingcart" type="antdesign" size={30} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ShowProductScreen;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  mainContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },
  flatListContainer: {
    padding: 8,
  },
  itemButton: {
    margin: 8,
    padding: 16,
    borderColor: '#7CAF58',
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  productContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  image: {
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
  },
  textContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginLeft: 16,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'black',
    fontSize: 16,
  },
});
```

and the error is navigating to the line that contains:
`const category = route.params.categoryId`

I really confused to solve that right now because I have tried so many ways to solve that from Stack Overflow and until now I don't know how to solve that so I consider to ask in this forum. Can you help me to solve that?

Comment: Log `route` to see what it is, I am assuming it is undefined as well.

Try getting hold of route by using the hook, `const route = useRoute();`

Answer (score 0):

if it's saying 'Cannot read property 'categoryId' of undefined', is not the categoryId that is undefined but the params.

try: route?.params?.categoryId
maybe in the first render the property isn't available.

i also recommend to put everything that is coming undefined in a useEffect hook with console.log, helps a lot to understand whats is happening.

Comment: Agreed. Try logging the values to check if the values are actually getting fetched.

Answer (score 0):

Use **hooks i.e. useRoute()** instead of props routes

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).